# Sublime Text: Untitled document, variables autocompletion?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

It's my first day using Sublime. After simple test, I could not find this function: for a newly created document, BEFORE saving, Sublime seems to be not able to remember variables I've inputed, thus can not autocomplete.
Am I wrong? Any plugin to fix this?

Comment: What language are you using? Have you set the correct syntax for the file? For example, if you're programming in JavaScript, does it say `JavaScript` at the very bottom right of the window? If you haven't set the syntax, auto complete will not work.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Now I find 2 ways: TAB key (which is good enough for me), and set a random syntax.

Comment: What do you mean use the Tab key or set a "random" syntax? Aren't you programming?

Comment: @MattDMo For example, after defining variable xa=1,xb=2, I can input "x" then with TAB key, Sublime will switch between xa and xb.......I could set any syntax in lower right corner, then autocomplete is ok EVENIF it's an untitled document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of sublime text plugins available online to help you get rid of that problem. It depends on what kind of plugin you wanted and for what purpose.

These are some of autocomplete plugins available:

1. [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/)
2. [Auto Close HTML Tags](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Auto%20Close%20HTML%20Tags)
3. [All Autocomplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete)

> Note: Before you can add plugins, You need to first install `Sublime
>   Package Control`. Check [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)